# Is it possible to hide sidebar in Streamlit?

Tags: sidebar, streamlit

I have a Logout button in the sidebar. I want to hide/disappear the complete sidebar when I click the Logout button. This my code

```
import streamlit as st
name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login("Login","main")
if authenticator.logout("Logout", "sidebar"):
    st.markdown("""
      <style>
          [data-testid="collapsedControl"] {
                display: none
            }
       </style>
       """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

I tried this [Completely disable sidebar?](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/completely-disable-sidebar/35463). But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect this markdown to solve your problem.

```py
st.markdown("""
    <style>
        section[data-testid="stSidebar"][aria-expanded="true"]{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: ```
     st.markdown("""
            <style>
                .css-vk3wp9.e1akgbir11{
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
     ```